# Failed to install backdoor-apk

Tags: operating-systems

I tried to install the backdoor-apk on Kali Nethunter and I received the following **error**:

```
[*] Running backdoor-apk.sh v0.2.4a on Mon Feb 15 05:23:28 UTC 2021
[!] Check your environment and configuration. Couldn't find: baksmali
```

I have already researched in several places and I have not found any solution, there is this post on Github but I couldn't find a solution:

> https://github.com/dana-at-cp/backdoor-apk/issues/164

Can someone give me a step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was much simpler than I thought, I needed to install apktool so I went and ran the **following command:**

```
sudo apt install smali apktool
```

I didn't have the jarsigner installed so I researched the latest version of headless jdk I used the **following command:**

```
apt search jdk
```

**And then I found this:**

```
openjdk-17-jdk-headless // Latest version
```

**And then I installed it with the following command:**

```
apt-get install openjdk-17-jdk-headless
```

And anyway, I managed to run the normal script :)

Guys, it seems simple but I didn't find much article about this problem in English, but I solved it thanks to this site in Chinese:

> https://www.cnblogs.com/sillage/p/14053636.html